# Make a two-dimensional 10x2 array, each element set to the string "x"

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

As the title suggests, I want to create an array that outputs the following but I don't have an idea on how to do this:

```
x x
x x
x x
x x
x x
x x
x x
x x
x x
x x
```

And here's the code I started working on to do this:

```java
public static void designs() {
    String[][] canvas = new String[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < canvas[0].length; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                canvas[j][i] = "x";
            } else {
                canvas[j][i] = "x";
            }
        }
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < canvas.length; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < canvas[0].length; b++) {
            System.out.print(canvas[a][b] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create an 10x10 array instead of a 10x2 one (`new String[10][2]`) and do some strange manipulation when `canvas[i][j] = "x";` would be enough, here:

```java
if (i == j) {
    canvas[j][i] = "x";
} else {
    canvas[j][i] = "x";
}
```

Which actually is equivalent to

```java
canvas[j][i] = "x";
```

Looks like you just confused the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create matrix contains characters then you should create the matrix of characters data type so that size can be optimized.

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

        // For taking input from user : console input
        InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);

        System.out.println("Enter the size of rows : ");
        int rows = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the size of columns : ");
        int cols = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        Character[][] canvas = new Character[rows][cols];

        for (int i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < canvas[0].length; j++) {
                canvas[i][j] = 'x';
            }
        }

        //for each loop
        for (Character[] lines : canvas) {
            for (Character car : lines) {
                System.out.print(car + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a 2d array `10x2` and filling it with symbols [`X`](https://unicode-table.com/en/0058/):

```java
int m = 10;
int n = 2;
String[][] arr = IntStream.range(0, m)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, n)
                // a string with the symbol X
                .mapToObj(j -> "X")
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(arr).map(row -> String.join(" ", row)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
X X
X X
X X
X X
X X
X X
X X
X X
X X
X X
```